# Specify minimum step in constrained minimization in SciPy

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, minimization

I am trying to perform optimization where the minimum step size is specified, in scipy.

I know that annealing can do this, but it can only use bound constraint. I am thinking about slsqp or nelder-mead, but cannot figure out how to define minimum step size.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!